# ffmpeg-add a transition video at the end of main video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two videos, the main video is 5 seconds long and created from a still images, dimensions are 720x480, the second video is a 1 second long transition video, the original dimensions were 1920x1080 this file had alpha so that the transition can show the image/video in the background.

What I want to do is:

1. convert the original 1920x1080 file to a 720x480 dimension video without loosin the alpha channel
2. create a 30fps video from a still image which is 5 seconds long (my current video is 25fps)
3. overlay the transition video which is 1 second long to the end of the main video at 4th second so that the transition plays just before the end of the main video.

Following is the ffprobe out for transition file:

```
F:\ffmpeg test>ffprobe -i 3D_Transition_02.mp4
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3D_Transition_02.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-04-27T15:23:17.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:01.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2345 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 2028 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-27T15:23:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-27T15:23:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
```

The following is the ffprobe from the file i created from the original transition animation, there is clearly a difference in both files:

```
F:\ffmpeg test>ffprobe -i transition.mp4
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transition.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 628 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, 622 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not clear what the Q is. Do you want the command for applying the transition. Your original transition is H264, so it won't have an alpha channel. It has to be exported using a codec that supports alpha, like PNG or Quicktime Animation or ProRes. Also, the aspect ratio of 1920x1080 and 720x480 aren't the same, so the transition will be distorted once resized. What's the reason for 720x480, is it meant for NTSC broadcast/DVD use?

Comment: Yes, I want to apply the transition. But before that I need to convert the transition to 720x480 as I am trying to create the video for YouTube and that size is quite suitable. Once I have the transition down to that size with alpha channel I want to apply it onto my main video. The main video is already of the size 720x480

Comment: How did you create the original transition file? YT prefers 16:9 ratio videos, so 720x480 is not suitable.

Comment: I actually bought it from envato.  can share both the transition and main video if there is a way here. My main video i created using still image and the lenght is 5 seconds.

Comment: Just share the main video and the link to the envato video page.

Comment: its part of a mega pack so it won't be directly accessible. better still, here is a google drive link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WXbUpxEMaMEtew9R-x5RgFmtp5l3QbC4?usp=sharing

I have shared the video that I have created and the transition video. Hope that helps you help me. I want to overlay the transition over the main in the begining as well as an option to overlay it in the end of the main video so that when I stich up/concat several videos the transitions can be seen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77112/discussion-between-amin-baig-and-gyan).

Comment: Ok, the transition video doesn't have an alpha channel; it is meant to be added to the main video as an alpha channel. And the effect only makes sense when you combine it with another main video. It should only be added to the end. Share a link to two still images, and I'll supply a command in a while.

Comment: I have uploaded the two images in the shared folder here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WXbUpxEMaMEtew9R-x5RgFmtp5l3QbC4 

and you were right, the size for youtube 720p would be 1280x720 so that means I will have to rescale/render both the transition and main video.

Also, can you do it with video files? I have uploaded a1 and a2 mp4 files as well as the transition will be between video files concated together.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks man, really appreciate it. Looking forward to try it out.

Comment: @Gyan if I may ask, when would it be possible for you to provide command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to do this in two steps.

First step creates an image file with alpha, using the transition:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -i 3D_Transition_02.mp4 
       -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba,scale=1280:720,split[img][a];
                        [1]format=rgb24,negate,scale=1280:720[tr];
                        [a][tr]overlay=format=gbrp[al];
                        [img][al]alphamerge,setsar=1,format=yuva444p"
       -an -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 0 -quality realtime -auto-alt-ref 0 a1vp8.mkv
```

This creates a 5 second still image file with the 1.75s transition effect added as an alpha channnel at the beginning. You'll not be able to see the alpha channel in regular players.

In second step, these processed image videos can be combined

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i a1vp8.mkv -c:v libvpx -i a2vp8.mkv
       -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS+3.25/TB[a2];
                        [0][a2]overlay"   out.mp4
```

Since transition duration is 1.75s, that should be overlap time between the two images. So, the timestamps of the 2nd input are delayed to start at 3.25s.

---

For 5 inputs prepared in the same way, use

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i a1vp8.mkv -c:v libvpx -i a2vp8.mkv -c:v libvpx -i a3vp8.mkv
       -c:v libvpx -i a4vp8.mkv -c:v libvpx -i a5vp8.mkv
       -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS+3.25/TB[a2];
                        [2]setpts=PTS+6.50/TB[a3];
                        [3]setpts=PTS+9.75/TB[a4];
                        [4]setpts=PTS+13.00/TB[a5];
                        [0][a2]overlay[o2];
                        [o2][a3]overlay[o3];
                        [o3][a4]overlay[o4];
                        [o4][a5]overlay"   out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks Gyan, works like a charm :-)

Just one last question regarding the first step, if it was a video file, would the command be the same. for example if it was a video from youtube or any other source we would just replace the file name?

Comment: Yes, remove `-framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5` and replace the filename

Comment: This is for 2 videos. If I prepared 5 images using the first step, how should I restructure the second statement?  I know that the first line will contain all the videos I have created, how should I modify the second part -filter_complex portion to accommodate the 3, 4 and fifth video?

Comment: Added new command

Comment: Thanks Gyan. Much appreciated. Reading through the documents now to get a better understanding of the syntax

Comment: I have been trying to understand the concept of what the values in the [] represent. for example what does [1] represent, and [a2] and then [o2], how do we decide which values to write in these brackets.